# CSS inexplicable image width - Very weird behavior only in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have no way to explain this:

on [this page](http://www.memoryaid.org/), the left most button in the middle of the page (reads "DOCTOR APPROVED") is limited to a width of 80px, and I have absolutely not idea why... it's even more interesting that when I move the mouse over the button it goes back to the normal width... this happens only on chrome, reproduced on different machines.

Comment: looks like `-webkit-transition` is causing problems. Try to remove this line from `base.css` on line 103

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the inline style - `style="margin-left: 40px;"` from here

```
<img src="/files/images/banner3001left.png" class="homepage-box" style="margin-left: 40px;">
```

it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this locally, so I have several suggestions:

- Remove the margin-left from the image.
- Put a div-wrapper around those buttons, just for clarity
- Give those p.homepage-box-p a width